# Help with probability, expected values

Tags: probability, expected-value

[Question: Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGw89.png)

> Consider  random variable $X$ over the positive integers, satisfying $P[X=i] = C/i^2$ for any integer $i>0$, where $C^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/i^2$, what is $\mathsf E(X)$?

I am learning expected values, but I am not sure what this question is asking. They have given me the formula for $X$ which is $C/i^2$.

However why did they give me $C^{-1}$?

I know that $E(X) = X * Pr(X)$

But how do I apply it to this questions?

Thank you

Disclaimer: this is a weekly school tutorial and we are allowed to discuss but I do not know anyone to ask. Some guidance would be great!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You (usually) need to know C to compute $E[X]$. You could have computed it yourself using the requirement that $\sum_i C/i^2 =1$, if you knew how to compute $\sum_i 1/i^2 $ (which is more advanced), but they gave it to you. It is not true that $E[X]=X \cdot P(X)$, but rather $E[X]=\sum_i i \cdot P(i)$

Answer (score 1):

> They have given me the formula for $X$ which is $C/i^2$.
>
> However why did they give me $C^{-1}$?

As a *distraction*, or to assure you that the total probability equals $1$.   Well, rather, if the formula is to be a proper probability mass function over that domain, then that is what $C$ must equal. $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathsf P(X=i)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (C/i^2)\\&=1\end{align}$$

Well, you *could* use this to find $C$, but you don't need to.

$\tiny 1/\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i^{-2} =6/\pi^2$

> I know that $E(X) = X * Pr(X)$

It does not.

You should know that $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i\cdot\mathsf P(X=i)\\&=\end{align}$$

So it's trivial to find the series formula.

$\color{silver}{\tiny\text{Don't worry about trying to find a closed form, as this series fails the convergence test.}}$

Comment: It is obvious the series for $E(X)=C\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{i}$ is divergent